# How to connect to class component without passing props typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I started learning React with TypeScript and today I encountered a problem - I can't connect to component without passing data.

For example

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import { PostInterface } from './pages/Posts';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import FullPost from './pages/FullPost';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PostsContainer from './pages/PostsContainer';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Header image="https://www.linagro.tn/images/slider/slides/1920x400/southern-alps-1920x400.png" text="posts" />
            <PostsContainer />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/posts/:id">
            <Header image="https://www.linagro.tn/images/slider/slides/1920x400/southern-alps-1920x400.png" text="post" />
            <FullPost text="Post" title="It's my post" createdAt={Date.now} author="noname" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I wanna render PostsContainer without passing there any props because the component will get the props using connect with react redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Posts from './Posts';

class PostsContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Posts posts={this.props.posts} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PostsContainer);
```

I get two errors:

Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Object is possibly 'undefined'.

How can I render PostsContainer without passing data?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you havn't specified what kind of props PostsContainer takes, so by default it's assumed it doesn't take any props. Then when you try to use mapStateToProps to pass it a `posts` prop, typescript complains.

The fix is to update the types to include a posts prop:

```
interface PostsContainerProps {
  // not sure exactly what the type on the posts prop is, but assuming 
  // you have a Post type defined somewhere, maybe something like:
  posts: Post[],
}

class PostsContainer extends Component<PostsContainerProps> {
  // rest is unchanged
```

Comment: But then i must pass posts in PostsContainer and i should get data from connect

Comment: Did you try updating the types the way i suggested? Your code looks like it will work with those types, including the part where you render `<PostsContainer />` without any explicit props. `connect`'s type definition is smart enough to know which props need to be passed in externally and which do not.

Comment: I changed that to this

interface PostInterface {
    title: string,
    text: string,
    createdAt?: any,
    author?: string
}

interface PostsContainerProps {
    posts: PostInterface[],
}

Comment: class PostsContainer extends Component<PostsContainerProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Posts posts={this.props.posts} />
        )
    }
}

Comment: And you're saying typescript started complaining about `<PostsContainer />`? What's the error it's giving you?

Comment: Property 'posts' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<PostsContainerProps, "posts">'.

Comment: That implies that mapStateToProps is not returning a `posts` property, so `connect` thinks it still needs to be passed in. Maybe it's because you are using any for your state object. Try adding an explicit return type to your mapStateToProps function `const mapStateToProps = (state: any): { posts: PostInterface[] } => {`

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state: any): { posts: PostInterface[] } => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    }
}